# Confusion with "this" object in JavaScript anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Hi I have following JavaScript code that I am trying to run. My aim is to grasp the meaning of `this` in different scopes and different types of invocations in JavaScript.

If you look in code below: I have a inner anonymous function, which is getting assigned to `innerStuff` variable. In that anonymous function as such `this` points to `window` object and not the outer function object or anything else. Event though it still has access to out function's variables.

Anyway, I am not sure, why that would be; but if you look at code below, I pass `this` in form of `that` to `innerStuff` later and it works just fine and prints object with `doofus` attribute in console.

```
    var someStuff = {
        doofus:"whatever",
        newF: function()
        {
            var that = this;
            console.log(that);
            var innerStuff = function(topThis){
                console.log(topThis);
            };

            return innerStuff(that);
        }
    }

    someStuff.newF();
```

Now I am changing a code only little bit. And instead of assigning it to `innerStuff`, I'll just directly return the function by invoking it as shown below:

```
    var someStuff = {
        doofus:"whatever",
        newF: function()
        {
            var that = this;
            console.log(that);
            return function(that){
                console.log(that);
            }();
        }
    }

    someStuff.newF();
```

This prints undefined for the inner anonymous function. Is it because there is a clash between a `that` that is being passed as parameter and a `that` defined in outside function? 
I thought the parameter would have overriden the visibility. Why would the value be not retained?

This is utterly confusing.

On the other hand if I don't pass `that`, but instead just use it, because visibility is there, the outcome is proper and as expected.

What is it that I am missing? Is it the clash between the variables, present in same scope?
Is there a good reason, that inner functions have `this` bound to `window` object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript refers to the object that you called a method on. If you invoke a function as `someObject.functionName(args)`, then `this` will be bound to that object. If you simply invoke a bare function, as in `functionName(args)`, then `this` will be bound to the `window` object.

Inside of `newF` in the second example, you are shadowing the `that` variable in your inner function, but not passing anything into it, so it is undefined.

```
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(that){
            console.log(that);
        }();
```

You probably want the following instead, if you want something that is equivalent to your first example (passing `that` in to the inner function):

```
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(that){
            console.log(that);
        }(that);
```

Or the following, if you don't want to shadow it and just use the outer function's binding:

```
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(){
            console.log(that);
        }();
```

Comment: ah!! can't believe I missed that. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Well, it *is* completely different to how bound methods work in every other language that has them...

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, when you invoke the anonymous function, the parameter `that` is not defined (you aren't passing anything to it.)  You can do this:

```
    newF: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(that){
            console.log(that);
        }(that); // note that we are passing our 'that' in as 'that'
    }
```

That will keep the proper value of the variable around.

However, since you are scoping `var that` above, you could just remove the function parameter as well:

```
    newF: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(){
            console.log(that);
        }(); // 'that' is referenced above.
    }
```

As far as why anonymous functions have `window` as their `this`:  whenever you call a function without a context (i.e. `somef()` vs `context.somef()`) `this` will point to the `window` object.

You can override that and pass a `this` using [`.apply(context, argumentsArray)` or `.call(context, arg1, arg2, arg3)`](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html) on a function.  An example:

```
    newF: function()
    {
        console.log('Outer:', this);
        var innerF = function(){
            console.log('Inner:', this);
        };
        return innerF.apply(this,arguments);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first code example, the anonymous function, though declared within a function that is a member of the `someStuff` object, is not a member of the `someStuff` object. For that reason, `this` in that function is a reference to the window object. If you wanted to invoke the anonymous function and have control over the `this` reference, you could do the following:

```
var someStuff = {
    doofus:"whatever",
    newF: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        var innerStuff = function(){
            console.log(this);
        };

        return innerStuff.apply(this);
    }
}

someStuff.newF();
```

In your second example, your actually creating an anonymous function, executing it, and then returning the value that the anonymous function returned. However, your anonymous function did not return anything. Additionally, you have a variable name conflict. You could do:

```
var someStuff = {
    doofus:"whatever",
    newF: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        console.log(that);
        return function(){
            console.log(that);
            return true;
        }();
    }
}

someStuff.newF();
```

I added the return true because your function should return something, since the function that is executing it is returning the return value of the anonymous function. Whether it returns true or false or a string or an object or whatever else depends on the scenario.

Comment: I agree with first point that I could use a "apply" invocation, but second point is incorrect. There is no name conflict as the passed parameter does override the param in outer function.

The mistake I did was that I didn't pass the param to the anonymous function while making the call. [As shown by Brian in example above] He stands corrected as his suggested solution worked just fine.

As for return value; I don't think so I cared too much; I just wanted to see how the value of this/that was being scoped inside the inner function.

Thanks for your help though.