# Use of this when calling methods from another

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have an object with several methods that looks like this one:

```
var obj = {
    method1: function(){
        $.get('/echo/json/', this.method2)
    },
    method2: function(){
        var $this = this;
        $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function(){
            $this.method3()
        })
    },
    method3: function(){
    }

}

obj.method1();
```

when I invoke the first method of my object I get this error (http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/p2gsn5gm/):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $this.method3 is not a function
```

I thought that referencing `this` before entering the callback did the job, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion with "this" object in JavaScript anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981498/confusion-with-this-object-in-javascript-anonymous-functions)

Comment: @Jamiec that question has only one method in the object... instead of many like mine. I appreciate that answer, but my case is a bit more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are successfully passing the value of `this` from `method2` to the JSON callback function.

The problem is that the value of `this` in `method2` is not what you expect.

Here:

> ```
> $.get('/echo/json/', this.method2)
> ```

You are passing the `method2` function and it is being called without the context of the object.

You need to preserve the value there.

The easiest way to do that is with `bind`.

```
 $.get('/echo/json/', this.method2.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an external reference to this, otherwise this gets bound to whatever the handler assigns to it ( handled by what I am assuming is jQuery '$')

```
var obj = (function(){ 

   var that = {
     method1: function(){
      $.get('/echo/json/', this.method2)
     },
     method2: function(){
       $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function(){
        that.method3();
       })
     },
     method3: function(){

     }
   };

   /* Fill it out with the methods you want */

   return that;
})();
```

Now should behave as you expected