# Why is variable undefined even if it's defined?

Tags: typescript

I am creating app for mobile device using Ionic framework. So as you can see, I created loading bar, and I want to dismiss it after everything is done. But also I want to change my booleans. But console says they are undefined. Why?

```
export class AfterEditPage {

    public loaded_image = base64Image;
    public showMainContent: boolean = true; // I am interacting with this one
    public showAdditionalContent: boolean = false; // and this one
    public processing_Result: string = "";

    constructor(public loadingctrl: LoadingController, public alertctrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    }

    recognizeImage() {

    let resultText;
    console.log(resultText);
    let loader = this.loadingctrl.create({
            content: 'Processing...'
    });

    console.log(this.processing_Result);
    loader.present().then(() => {
            Tesseract.recognize(this.loaded_image)
            .progress(function  (p) {})
            .then(function (result) {
                    resultText = result.text; console.log(resultText);
                    loader.dismiss().then(() => {
                            this.showMainContent = !this.showMainContent; // undefined
                    this.showAdditionalContent = !this.showAdditionalContent; // undefined
                    });
                });
              });
         }
    }
```

Comment: Two words:  [Arrow functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this).

Comment: Arrow functions here `then(function (result) {`

Comment: `this` is the global object here and not your instance of `AfterEditPage`.

Comment: @alexanderbird Thanks, that really helped me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion with "this" object in JavaScript anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981498/confusion-with-this-object-in-javascript-anonymous-functions)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions so you need to change your code to

```
 loader.present().then(() => {
            Tesseract.recognize(this.loaded_image)
            .progress((p) => {})
            .then((result) => {
                    resultText = result.text; console.log(resultText);
                    loader.dismiss().then(() => {
                            this.showMainContent = !this.showMainContent; 
                    this.showAdditionalContent = !this.showAdditionalContent;
                    });
                });
              });
         }
    }
```